# MSChart CreateControl launches Windows installer

Tags: c++, mfc

I have this code below trying to initialize CMSChart in a DLL I have created. When it gets to myChart->CreateControl, for some reason it is launching a Windows Installer dialog, and says 'Preparing to install...' indefinitely. I am no longer able to use this DLL as this install dialog pops up and never exits. Any reason why CreateControl would launch a windows installer dialog?

```
CMSChart *myChart = new CMSChart();
if( myChart )
{
    RECT    rect;
    rect.left = rect.top = 0;
    rect.right = rect.bottom = 10;

    //Create the control and makre sure it actually creates the window
    if( !myChart->CreateControl(myChart->GetClsid(), _T("Whatever"), WS_POPUP, rect, CWnd::GetDesktopWindow(), 99) ||
        !myChart->m_hWnd )
    {
        HINSTANCE   dllInst = LoadLibrary( _T("MSCHRT20.OCX") );
        HRESULT     rc = 0;
        if( dllInst )
        {
            typedef HRESULT (*STDAPIFUNC) (void);
            STDAPIFUNC  registerServerEntry = (STDAPIFUNC) GetProcAddress( dllInst, "DllRegisterServer" );
            if( registerServerEntry )
                registerServerEntry();
            FreeLibrary( dllInst );
        }
    }
    delete myChart;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you setting the desktop window as the parent?

Comment: It is supposed to be a feature.  The Office installer takes advantage of an MSI feature that can detect that the install of its components got corrupted.  Certainly the kind of mishap that can befall MSCHRT20.OCX.   It automatically launches the installer to help the user get it fixed.  Seems that it collapsed into a pile of rubble on this machine, re-installing Office would be the wise choice.

Comment: After removing Office and reinstalling a fresh copy of 2016, I still get this problem.

Comment: You have to find out the key path that MSI queries to detect the "corrupt" component. It can be a file or a registry entry. You could use Process Monitor to look for failed file and registry accesses.